# How to clean DOM node

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to remove unnecessary spaces and the head of a HTML node.

For example, for this node `p`:

```
<p>
   The cat 
   <b>
       <span>is on </span>
       <em><span>the bed</span></em>
   </b>
</p>
```

I would like to obtain:

```
<p>The cat <b><span>is on </span><em><span>the bed</span></em></b></p>
```

So that if `node` contains the DOM tree of root `p` and I execute the following code:

```
var text = node.innerText;
console.log(text);
```

I get `The cat` and not 
                     `The cat`

I found this method:

```
function clean(node)
{
  for(var n = 0; n < node.childNodes.length; n ++)
  {
    var child = node.childNodes[n];
    if
    (
      child.nodeType === 8 
      || 
      (child.nodeType === 3 && !/\S/.test(child.nodeValue))
    )
    {
      node.removeChild(child);
      n --;
    }
    else if(child.nodeType === 1)
    {
      clean(child);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried doing:

```
clean(node);
var text = node.innerText;
console.log(text);
```

and I obtain always 
                     `The cat`

Why? How can I solved my problem?

Thanks

---

If I had:

```
 <p>cat_</p>
```

or

```
 <p>
     cat_
 </p>
```

I would like to obtain always `cat_` and not 
       `cat_`

Comment: Just trim the value and no need to use any additional functions: `var text = node.innerText.trim();`

Comment: Just google `html uglify`

Comment: @dfsq If I do as you say I lose the spaces that may exist in a string..

Comment: Why do you think that code would do what you want? What do you think the `.removeChild()` method does?

Comment: No, trim will only remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Thanks for the reply. Why it is not correct?

Comment: **You are conflating the textual representation of the DOM with the actual in memory representation, they are not the same thing.** and from the comments what you are wanting is not clear.

Comment: @gongzhitaao What should I look for exactly? I tried google with what you say but I did not understand what I should do now..

Comment: @lonely: `"I lose the spaces that may exist in a string"` - If you want to keep the spaces then what exactly *are* you trying to do?

Comment: @David Keep the spaces that may exist in a innerText but remove those that are generated from representing the html with the indentation and the head (\n)..

Comment: Just copy code into [first link](http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/) you got a working example.  [html-uglifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-uglify) and [html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier) provide more control.

Comment: I add an example on the main message

Comment: @lonely: How can the code know the difference between whitespace characters you want to keep and ones you want to eliminate?  It sounds like you should clean the source markup to contain the content you want it to contain.

Comment: Sorry. I update the example in the main message. I saw now that the space was not displayed correctly. With `_` mean a space. Sorry again..

Answer (score 1):

You can use **String.prototype.trim()** method, it will remove leading an trailing spaces

```
var spaces = "       your text     "
var required = spaces.trim()
```

Now `required = "your text"`

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: @lonely At the beginning and end, yes, but that's what you asked for.

Comment: if you want that one space before and after, simply add it like `required = ' ' + required + ' '`

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I add an example on the main message. The string MAY contain spaces before and after. It depends on how the user of my application writes the text..

Comment: Does input contain tags ?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz text is always inside a SPAN tag. But `node` can be composed of different tags.

Comment: Kindly first explain well what do you want.. this is what you asked in your question. Edit your question so we can help you..

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Sorry. I update the example in the main message. I saw now that the space was not displayed correctly. With `_` mean a space. Sorry again..

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I'd prefer not, but I can try.

Comment: I created a fiddle , it's not perfect but you can make changes to get  100% https://jsbin.com/yurubo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
function whitespaceSimplify(str: string): string {
    str = str.replace(/\s+/g, " ") // Replace all whitespace in a row with a simple space sign
    return str
}
```

You can use this on the HTML-Code the remove any doublicated whitespaces:

```
clean(node);
node.innerHTML = whitespaceSimplify(node.innerHTML)
```

or use `whitespaceSimplify(string)` in clean

Demo:

```js
function clean(node) {
  for (var n = 0; n < node.childNodes.length; n++) {
    var child = node.childNodes[n];
    if (
      child.nodeType === 8 ||
      (child.nodeType === 3 && !/\S/.test(child.nodeValue))
    ) {
      node.removeChild(child);
      n--;
    } else if (child.nodeType === 1) {
      clean(child);
    }
  }
}

function whitespaceSimplify(str) {
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g, " ") // Replace all whitespace in a row with a simple space sign
  return str
}


var node = document.getElementById('node')
clean(node)
node.innerHTML = whitespaceSimplify(node.innerHTML)

document.getElementById('output').innerText = node.innerHTML
```

```html
<div id="node">
  <p>
    The cat 
    <b>
      <span>
        is on 
      </span>
      <em><span>the bed</span></em>
    </b>
  </p>
</div>
<code id="output"></code>
```

returns:
   `<p> The cat <b><span> is on </span><em><span>the bed</span></em></b></p>`

Comment: @lonely: yes, but only before the first tag and after the last tag, where there should be nothing ;) Wich is also irelavant to HTML. It should do exactly what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your help. No, I would need to maintain that there are spaces before and after a string. I updated the example of the main message so maybe you will understand better what I want ... Sorry

Comment: @lonely: indeed, sorry.. yes then we have to remove `trim` - I updated it, is it working as you want now?

Comment: @lonely: yes..`str.replace(/\s+/, " ")`  should be `str.replace(/\s+/g, " ")` - sorry :D

Comment: Ok, there something wrong in my code. Now I search the error. Thanks CodeSir!